# Parse python multiline traceback to one line with fluentbit

Tags: python, django, newrelic, fluentd, fluent-bit

My python application writing logs to STDOUT and I am collecting the logs with **fluentbit** agent. My logs sample

```
 
Checking for future activity
 
Activity Time: 1636487814
 
Current Time: 1636490831
 
Not the future activity request for athlete: 505
  
[2021-11-09 20:47:11,781] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1/lala/activity-request [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/framework_flask.py", line 64, in _nr_wrapper_handler_
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 467, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 582, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./test-app/api/resources/lala/v1/resources.py", line 111, in post
    lalaService.send_activity_request_to_broker(athlete, activity_request)
  File "./test-app/api/resources/lala/services.py", line 94, in send_activity_request_to_broker
    ThirdPartyService.produce_activity(activity_data)
  File "./test-app/api/resources/common/services.py", line 91, in produce_activity
    get_or_create_eventloop().run_until_complete(produce_activity(activity_data))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 587, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "./test-app/producer.py", line 12, in produce_activity
    await result
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending coro=<produce_activity() running at ./test-app/producer.py:12> cb=[remove_from_cache() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic/hooks/coroutines_asyncio.py:20, _run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:157]> got Future <Future pending cb=[Topic._on_published(message=<FutureMessage pending>, state={}, producer=<Producer: running >)()]> attached to a different loop
 
[pid: 10|app: 0|req: 15952/63804] 10.0.225.22 () {60 vars in 2181 bytes} [Tue Nov  9 20:47:11 2021] POST /api/v1/lala/activity-request => generated 37 bytes in 506 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 90 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
 
Duplicate request.id = 505 workout time = 2021-08-28T08:27:21.000Z
```

For traceback, I want to ship full traceback with one line.

Is it possible to do this with fluentbit parser?

Answer (score 2):

Fluent Bit support parsing multi-line messages, you just have to identify:

1. What identifies the first line of a log message. In your case all the messages start with a space followed by a newline (\n) character. Regex: `^\s\n`
2. What makes the other lines in a log message. It's easy: it's not a space-newline (`^(?!\s\n).+`).

From this point just edit the sample code from the [documentation](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/administration/configuring-fluent-bit/multiline-parsing).

parsers_multiline.conf:

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-regex-test
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    # rules |   state name  | regex pattern         | next state
    # ------|---------------|-----------------------------------
    rule      "start_state"   "/^\s\n/"               "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/^(?!\s\n).+/"         "cont"
```

fluent-bit.conf:

```
[SERVICE]
    (...)
    parsers_file parsers_multiline.conf

[INPUT]
    name             tail
    path             test.log
    read_from_head   true
    multiline.parser multiline-regex-test

[OUTPUT]
    (...)
```

Comment: I have already read the document. Are you sure this gonna work? For fluentd, we can give a starting pattern & an ending pattern to detect multiline traceback. The problem was I have no confidence in the multiline ending patterns. For fluentbit, there already has some built-in parser for this purpose but they can't parse multiline properly. BTW, I resolved it by making the traceback transform into JSON and parse it. That's the easiest way I think.

Comment: @Thekira Yes, I have a similar pattern in production for fluent bit sidecars of django projects (the `start_state` recognise a `[timestamp] rest of the line` format, while `cont` pattern is "anything that does not start with brackets" (`/^[^\[].+/`).